# Переведите пожалуйста 4 строчку на js

Tags: javascript

```
1.  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
2.      var $sections = $('section');
3.      $sections.each(function(i,el){
4.          var top  = $(el).offset().top-300;
5.      })
6.  });
```