# Возникли проблемы с переводом с jq на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  var $sections = $('section');
  $sections.each(function(i,el){
    var top  = $(el).offset().top-300;
  })
});
```

Переведите 4 строчку  на нативный js пожалуйста .

Comment: Зачем? Этот код ничего полезного не делает.

Comment: Это вырезка с кода.Как я понял, он показывает расстояние от верха странице до секции .

Comment: зачем задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз?

Comment: Вопрос вроде просто, но ответа нету .Чтобы узнать как эта строчка будет на нативном JavaScript.

Comment: Ты уже задал точно такой же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/903704/186999

Comment: Он закрыт с пояснением: _Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему._

Comment: Почему, вместо редактирования того вопроса, ты просто задал то же самое, и опять без форматирования?

Comment: _Вопрос вроде просто_ - как ты определяешь простоту? :-) А вдруг не просто? ;-)

Comment: Так что тут редактировать, ясно и понятно написано что нужно перевести код на нативный JavaScript

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Четвертая строчка на нативном JavaScript будет выглядеть так
 var top = element.offsetTop;
 var x = top - 300;

Comment: Целых две переменных на одно вычитание.